# How to populate the dropdown ,values being returned from observer?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am subscribing the data from a service as :

```
this.infoService.getName()
        .subscribe((data)=>{
            console.log(data.json());
            this.names.push(data.json());
        });
```

And populating it into a dropdown list as follows:

```
<select  id='features' name='features'>
    <option *ngFor="let item of names">
      {{item}}
    </option> 
</select>
```

My issue is that whole response is coming in 0th position.As a result whole of the response is coming in the dropdown instead of a dropdown list.Can someone say what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `My issue is that whole response is coming in 0th position.` – Can you clarify this? What is the output of `console.log(data.json());` ?

Comment: what is response of `data`? is it an object or array ?

Comment: @Tommy the output is an array but my issue is that whole of the array is coming on dropdownlist.,instead it should come one below the other in a dropdown fashion.As a result I am getting a whole wide dropdown list

Comment: @hbamithkumara if i do push(data) the output on the button is response ok 200........

Comment: @micronyks its an array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` is type of array.

```
this.infoService.getName()
        .subscribe((data)=>{
             console.log(data.json());
            
             this.names = data;   // simply assign data array to this.names array 
});
```

---

if `Data` is string array means `["a", "b", "c"]`, it will output name without any change in html.

If `Data` is an array of objects `[{name:"a"}, {name:"b"}]`, change html as below,

```
<option *ngFor="let item of names">
      {{item.name}}                      // check this line
</option>
```

Comment: data is of type string array

Comment: 0: Response {_body: "["A","B","C","D"]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
length: 1

Comment: Data looks very strange.  print it without `.json()` and put it here.

Comment: its without json

Comment: then it has to be `this.names = data[0]._body` but still you have some problem somewhere.